# Escpos Thermal ZJ-58 Python Code128 Barcode print shows nothing

Tags: python, thermal-printer, escpos, barcode-printing, code128

```
from escpos.printer import Usb

p = Usb(0x0416, 0x5011, 0, 0x81, 0x03)
p.text("=================\n")
#p.image("./barcode/barcode.png")
#p.barcode('1324354657687', 'EAN13', 64, 2, '', './fonts/code128.ttf')
### barcode(code, bc, width, height, pos, font)
p.barcode("{B012ABCDabcd", "CODE128", function_type="B")
# Print QR Code
#p.qr("You can readme from your smartphone")
#p.cut()
#print(p.control('LF', 16))
#print(p.device)
```

I tried to print code128 and ean barcodes. I only got texts like;

> @1324354657687
>
> @I{B012ABCDabcd

. I've tried to add font file (which was not useful), to change code type and some other unuseful things. I researched the documents and manuals from internet. I could print text and image.

I use this https://github.com/escpos/python-escpos

The printer I use: Zijiang thermal ZJ-5890

Any idea why I get only letters but not barcode?

Answer (score 2):

The library you presented does not support Code128 barcodes when you look at the source code.
[python-escpos/escpos/escpos.py#L150](https://github.com/escpos/python-escpos/blob/master/escpos/escpos.py#L150)

> ```
> def barcode(self, code, bc, width, height, pos, font):
>     """ Print Barcode """
>     ... Omitted on the way ...
>     # Type 
>     if bc.upper() == "UPC-A":
>         self._raw(BARCODE_UPC_A)
>     elif bc.upper() == "UPC-E":
>         self._raw(BARCODE_UPC_E)
>     elif bc.upper() == "EAN13":
>         self._raw(BARCODE_EAN13)
>     elif bc.upper() == "EAN8":
>         self._raw(BARCODE_EAN8)
>     elif bc.upper() == "CODE39":
>         self._raw(BARCODE_CODE39)
>     elif bc.upper() == "ITF":
>         self._raw(BARCODE_ITF)
>     elif bc.upper() == "NW7":
>         self._raw(BARCODE_NW7)
>     else:
>         raise BarcodeTypeError()
>     # Print Code
> ```

There seems to be a library with the same name, so why not try using it?
[python-escpos 2.2.0](https://pypi.org/project/python-escpos/)
[python-escpos/python-escpos](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos)
[python-escpos - Python library to manipulate ESC/POS Printers](https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
[Printing Barcodes](https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/barcode.html)

> Escpos.barcode(code, bc, height=64, width=3, pos='BELOW', font='A', align_ct=True, function_type=None, check=True)
>
> Parameters
>
> - bc –
>   Possible values for type B:
>
>   - CODE128
>   - GS1-128
>
> **CODE128**
> Code128 barcodes need a certain format. For now the user has to make sure that the payload is correct. For alphanumeric CODE128 you have to preface your payload with {B.
>
> ```
> from escpos.printer import Dummy, Serial
> p = Serial()
> # print CODE128 012ABCDabcd
> p.barcode("{B012ABCDabcd", "CODE128", function_type="B")
> ```